# Join on datetime values

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to count the number of records based on matching a datetime values:

```
create table `weather` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `dt_iso` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `weather_main` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL);

insert into `weather` (`dt_iso`,`weather_main`) values ("2019-01-01 23:00:00","cloud"), ("2019-01-02 00:00:00","sun"), ("2019-01-02 01:00:00","cloud");

create table `incidents` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `Incident_Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL);

insert into `incidents` (`Incident_Date`) values ("2019-01-01 23:50:00"), ("2019-01-01 23:50:00"), ("2019-01-09 10:05:00");
```

In SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/489f57

This is the type of output I am seeking:

```
dt_iso, weather_main, count(incidents), 
2019-01-01T23:00:00, cloud, 0
2019-01-02T00:00:00, sun, 2
2019-01-02T01:00:00, cloud, 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to count incidents in the hour prior to the time in the `weather` table, which you can do with this query:

```
SELECT w.dt_iso, w.weather_main, COALESCE(COUNT(i.id), 0) AS incidents
FROM weather w
LEFT JOIN incidents i ON i.Incident_Date >  w.dt_iso - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
                     AND i.Incident_Date <= w.dt_iso
GROUP BY w.id
```

Output:

```
dt_iso                  weather_main    incidents
2019-01-01T23:00:00Z    cloud           0
2019-01-02T00:00:00Z    sun             2
2019-01-02T01:00:00Z    cloud           0
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/489f57/6)

Comment: I think it might be a count of incidents since the last entry, but as entries are hourly, I suppose it comes to the same thing

Comment: @Strawberry yes, not 100% clear but my interpretation was the same as yours i.e. that they are the same thing

Comment: I was thinking of rounding the incident times to the nearest hour, but this is a great solution too!

Comment: @Levi this solution has an advantage over rounding the times in that it can use an index on `Incident_Date`, where rounding those values would preclude that. You can also potentially rewrite it as `w.dt_iso < i.Incident_Date  + INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
                     AND w.dt_iso >=  i.Incident_Date` if that gives better performance